# How to fill a single MySQL table with certain columns from multiple CSV files?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a single MySQL table with information from multiple CSV files. These CSV files are parallel, but each contains a lot of extra columns that I don't need. Is there a way to create one MySQL table with select columns from multiple CSV files?

Comment: Load the data into staging tables and combine them after you load them.  Save yourself some grief.

Comment: Use command line utilities to create a single CSV file that has the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root'); // connect your db
mysql_select_db('yourdatabase');          // select your database
$files = glob('*.csv');                   // get the csv files

foreach($files as $file){                 // Loop through the file and do a LOAD DATA INFILE
    mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE yourtable");
}
```

If you need to drop csv columns, you could do the following

```
$ cut -d, -f2-4,7-9 --complement temp.csv 
1,5,6,10
1,5,6,10
1,5,6,10
1,5,6,10
1,5,6,10
1,5,6,10
1,5,6,10
```

The above removes all columns in range `2-4` and `7,9`

Or you can load the `.csv` into excel and manually remove the columns.